# Quarkus native image build with infinispan-client and grpc

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to build a native image for an application using **quarkus-infinispan-client** and **quarkus-grpc** w/o GraalVM installed with :
**mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -DskipTests**
The build fails with : **com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building** with some **netty** classes.
I have tried with **Quarkus 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8** with a minimal application having only the two dependencies added with the same result.
Can it be a bug or I am doing something wrong ? Is there any workaround ?
Also I get a lot of warnings with **Dependencies with duplicate files detected**
mainly in **wildfly** classes.
To reproduce the problem only the dependencies need to be defined in the pom
there is no need to use any of them.